# I have two siblings; we're locked in a war

Tags: riddle

> *I have two siblings; we're locked in a war.*
>   *One of them can grind me into the floor.*
>
> *As for the other, he could never win.*
>   *My razor-sharp wit makes me stronger than him.*

**Who or what am I?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are

> the scissors from Rock–paper–scissors

I have two siblings; we're locked in a war.

> Rock and paper

One of them can grind me into the floor.

> Rock, of course, smashs sissors

As for the other, he could never win.
My razor-sharp wit makes me stronger than him.

> Scissors cut paper

Comment: Aww 4 seconds, gj. Actually  wait do I delete mine now?

Comment: That was so fast, I can't even accept it yet.

Comment: And now I can. Well played.

Comment: @HollyLeaves No reason to delete yours ;)

Answer (score 24):

My first thought was:

> Rock Paper Scissors
>  You're the scissors

Answer (score 2):

My thought is that you are

> Scissors

Your sibling that can "grind [you] into the floor" is

> Rock

Your "other" sibling is

> Paper

Explanation:

> You and your siblings represent rock, paper, and scissors, from the game of the same name.  Your "razor-sharp wit" indicates the blade of scissors.  Your sibling can "grind you into the floor" because rock beats scissors.  Your other sibling could never win because paper loses to scissors.  As you said, you are "stronger than him".  In addition, you are all locked into a war because of the trifecta that you represent.  Rock > Scissors > Paper, but Paper > Rock.  None of you could ever win against both the others.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer submitted earlier?

Comment: @puzzledPig I didn't look at the other answers until I had submitted my response.  I wanted to remain uninfluenced by the others.  They did happen to be the same thing that I came up with.  I didn't attempt to delete my answer, since I feel it is more thorough than one of them.

Comment: (Independent work doesn't salvage a duplicate answer posted 6 hours later. Unless you can edit this answer to meaningfully differentiate it somehow from the one already given—and more verbose is not the same as more thorough—then deleting it is probably the best course here. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.... and on this one, ya got scooped!)